# Crud com Edição dentro da Própria tabela e busca de dados + banco de dados

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Alguém poderia me indicar uma forma de fazer um CRUD com edição pela própria tabela ? Detalhe essa tabela tem que estar lincada em um banco de dados, fiz ela em PHP com Busca, ficou show de bola, porem meu chefe não quis, ele quer algo mais simples ao usuário,

a pessoa entra na pagina onde os dados são exibidos clica na célula da tabela, edita o dado errado e PRONTO, salva o dado dela, não pode ter botões nem redirecionamento a outras paginas, tudo em uma pagina só...to quebrando a minha cabeça, tentei fazer em `JQUERY` mais vou ser sincero não sei linkar com o meu banco de dados e nem fazer a busca.

conheço um pouco de PHP, mais não foi o suficiente.

Alguém poderia me ensinar, me indicar um vídeo, me mostrar códigos qualquer coisa ajuda, emprego pode estar em jogo.

Answer (score 0):

Existe uma lib chamada [Bootstrap Table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/), eu uso em todos meus projetos, acho que é bem documentada e fácil de usar, existe uma extensão dela que tem exatamente oque você quer [aqui](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/editable.html). Vou deixar um exemplo da implementação da `lib` normal, nunca usei essa extensão de editar as informações direto das celulas.

Primeiro você cria uma table e dá um `id` pra ela:

```
              <table class="table" id="table">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th data-field="id" data-visible="false">ID</th>                       
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                </table>
```

Esse `data-field` vai ser o nome do atributo que a table receberá. Por exemplo, você devolve um `json` com a lista de pessoas, e o objeto pessoa no seu `php` provavelmente terá um `id`, colocando `data-field="id"` você está dizendo que naquela coluna ficará o `id` da pessoa.

Java Scrpit:

```
$("#table").bootstrapTable({
  ajax: urlQueVaiDevolverAListaDeJson,
  search: true, // se true, cria cria um campo de busca, e implementa a busca sozinho
  sidePagination: "client",
  pageSize: 5, // quantidade de itens por pagina.
  pagination: true // se true, cria uma paginação por você
});
```

Enfim.. é isso.. esse é o básico sobre o `bootstrap table`, ela faz muita coisa por você.. busca.. paginação.. e etc. Sugiro que você estude ela, e a extensão que tem oque você quer.